# Multiple observations AUC, Sensitivity and Specificity

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, auc, sensitivity-specificity

I am trying to find a CIs for the AUC, sensitivity and specificity. In my scenario, each observation consistent of a subject and an area examined, that is it is obvious that areas examined for the same person are dependent.

For each observation an classifier is applied (the truth is known) and the goal is to find CIs for AUC, sensitivity and specificity while considering the dependency. I tried using Generalized Estimating Equations (GEE) but it does not effect the results at all (same as if I assumed that each observation is independent).

Is there a standard approach to this kind of problem? How can I take into account the dependency when building CIs? Can bootstrap be used (sampling subjects)?